# Column Sum and subquery gives errors

Tags: mysql, having

I have one table where I want to know the outstanding balance of two the sum of columns

**The Table** looks something like this

```
journalid | senderid | sourcenr | accountnr | debitamount | creditamount | trxdate
```

**SQL QUERY**

```
 select j.senderid,

 (sum(j.debitamount)-(select sum(j2.creditamount)as balance from
 journal j2 where j2.sourcenr = j.sourcenr and j2.ccaountnr =
 3993200))as outstanding

  from journal j

 where j.accountnr = 3993200

 and( j.trxdate >= '2012-12-31' and j.trxdate < '2013-01-31')

 group by 1

 having (sum(j.debitamount)-(select sum(j2.creditamount)as balance from
 journal j2 where j2.source = j.source and j2.accnr = 3993200)) > 0

 order by 1
```

I get the following error -

> Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).

If I add the `sourcenr` field (as shown below)

```
 select j.senderid,
         j.sourcenr,

    (sum(j.debitamount)-(select sum(j2.creditamount)as balance from
 journal j2 where j2.sourcenr = j.sourcenr and j2.ccaountnr =
 3993200))as outstanding

    from journal j

 where j.accountnr = 3993200

 and( j.trxdate >= '2012-12-31' and j.trxdate < '2013-01-31')

 group by 1 ,2

 having (sum(j.debitamount)-(select sum(j2.creditamount)as balance from
 journal j2 where j2.source = j.source and j2.accnr = 3993200)) > 0

 order by 1
```

Then I DON'T get the error, but I don't get **unique rows** for senderid **PLEASE HELP** !!!

Comment: Could you please add a example on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/?